When I try to install dlib, I get ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib, but I have already installed cmake
I am running on Raspberry Pi Bookworm, with all updates installed. I installed cmake using both pip and apt, and have verified that by running cmake --version, which returns
cmake version 3.29.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

I have also run pip list, and it tells me that cmake is in fact installed.
I tried to install cmake with both apt and pip, which both seemed to work. However, when I run pip install dlib, or use pip3, it begins to work but then errors:
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/argetlam/f_recognition/env/bin/cmake", line 5, in <module>
          from cmake import cmake
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'
      
      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib
      
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I have also tried to upgrade pip and install wheel, neither of which have worked. I have gone through many stack overflow posts and have tried all of those methods as well. I also tried this:
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install -y cmake
which outputs this:
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease        
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.com/debian bookworm InRelease                 
Ign:5 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bookworm InRelease                        
Err:6 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bookworm Release
  404  Not Found [IP: XX.XXX.XXX.XX 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu bookworm Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Anyone know how I could fix this?

/home/argetlam/f_recognition/env/bin/ it seems you use a virtual environment but sudo apt-get install cmake installs it globally, outside of any virtual environments. Try to install cmake in the virtual environment: /home/argetlam/f_recognition/env/bin/pip install -U cmake

When I try that, it just outputs Requirement already satisfied: cmake in ./env/lib/python3.11/site-packages (3.29.2)

/home/argetlam/f_recognition/env/bin/python -c "from cmake import cmake" ?

I can run import cmake  just fine, but from cmake import cmake  raises ImportError: cannot import name ‘cmake’ from ‘cmake’ 

You don't have any cmake.py around, not related to real CMake? With real CMake from cmake import cmake must work.

I don't. Also- running which cmake -a gives me /usr/bin/cmake, but there is no directory named cmake in /usr/bin. Will add this to the post as well.

I got /home/argetlam/f_recognition/env/bin/python -c "from cmake import cmake" to work by upgrading the packages, but dlib still has the same ModuleNotFoundError
